# XNA changing color alpha

Tags: xna, color, alpha

I know I can take a color and multiply it by a float to reduce its alpha like that:

```
Color color = Color.Green * 0.15f;
```

But how do I return the color's alpha to it's original value?

I tried doing this:

```
color.A = 255;
```

But it seems like I get a different color. (The RGB are different then those of the original color).

Also, just changing the alpha of the original color (directly, not by multiplying) doesn't make it transparent..

Comment: Divide by the same amount.

Comment: It isn't possible to divide for some reason..

Comment: @Ofir See how http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color_members.aspx has an op_Multiply function? This is why color * float works. There is no op_Division but this should work `color = color * (1 / .15)`.

Comment: How silly - but yes, just use inverted mulitplication. Thanks @ClassicThunder

Comment: It works but It's not 100% accurate. Thanks anyway, I'll just do it in another way.

Answer (score -2):

You are multiplying all color components, not only the alpha channel (`Color.Green * 0.15f;`) To only change the alpha:

```
Color color = Color.Green;
color.A *= 0.15f;
```

Comment: This is wrong because it is not taking into account the fact that he is using XNA and thus premultiplied alpha.

Comment: Like I wrote in my post, directly changing the alpha doesn't make the object transparent.

Comment: -1 because Xna uses premultiplied alpha